# Why does SkiaSharp fail to load some image in UWP when calling SKBitmap.Decode?

Tags: uwp, skiasharp

This is totally strange.

I am trying to load images in UWP with `StorageFile` using the following code:

```cs
using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
    // the rest
}
```

However, some pictures fail at the line of calling `SKBitmap.Decode`, with this error message:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer
```

I check the stream in debugger, it is not null and it has value. I even put this later:

```
                        if (stream.CanRead && stream.CanSeek)
                        {
                            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        }
```

Those files always fail. For example, one is this:

[image]

I am not sure if anyone else can reproduce it with this image I upload to SO.
Also, I have opened all restriction, so it's not about permission. This photo can be displayed get calling `GetThumbnailAsync`, so the app setting is fine.

---

Now it is the strangest thing. If I do this:

```
                        SKImage img = SKImage.FromEncodedData(stream);
                        SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.FromImage(img);
```

It works for those photos!

This drives me crazy!

I mean, I found a way to make it work, but why?

Comment: I've just encountered the same error with one if my images. Any solution on this?

Comment: I have a solution in the question, basically you don't directly Decode to SKBitmap from the stream, instead, load it to an SKImage first, and then convert to a Bitmap, then it works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 

still no idea why it happens, but I created the issue and it's still open: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1621

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted your issue in github and will give your solution a try.

Comment: another "solution" is to downgrade possibly to 2.80.2

Answer (score 0):

That was a [bug](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1752), that got fixed in [2.88.3](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1752#issuecomment-1261739228). Update to 2.88.3 to solve that issue:

```
dotnet add package SkiaSharp --version 2.88.3
```